# Can someone explain this regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

```
/^[\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}\p{Lt}\p{Lu}\p{Nd}]+$/mu
```

This is the regular expression validation that cakePHP uses to validate alphanumeric strings. I am unable to understand what Ll, Lm, Lt etc are? This is to validate alphanumeric strings, so they should test for numbers and characters. Could someone explain this expression a little.

Thank you.

Comment: That's not a regex - someone just leant on the keyboard. Or something. (Boo, hiss, etc.)

Comment: Well I actually copied it and pasted from cakePHP's developer API. You could try that in PHP to verify if the string is alphanumeric.

Comment: Just jesting- it's clearly a regex (seems to be doing some fun Unicode character set things).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ll, Lm, Lo, Lt, Lu, Nd are unicode character classes.

See here at around 1/3 of the page:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

> - \p{Ll} or \p{Lowercase_Letter}: a
>     lowercase letter that has an uppercase
>     variant.
> - \p{Lu} or \p{Uppercase_Letter}: an uppercase
>     letter that has a lowercase variant.
> - \p{Lt} or \p{Titlecase_Letter}: a
>     letter that appears at the start of a
>     word when only the first letter of the
>     word is capitalized.
> - \p{L&} or \p{Letter&}: a letter that exists in
>     lowercase and uppercase variants
>     (combination of Ll, Lu and Lt).
> - \p{Lm} or \p{Modifier_Letter}: a special
>     character that is used like a letter.
> - \p{Lo} or \p{Other_Letter}: a letter
>     or ideograph that does not have
>     lowercase and uppercase variants.

Answer (score 1):

The code between the curly brackets (Li, Lm, Lt, etc) are classes of Unicode characters. A quick google for Unicode character classes produces for example the following list: http://www.siao2.com/2005/04/23/411106.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you regularily stumble upon weird regular expressions, try one of these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world - albeit I'm not sure if they explain those (mostly Unicode?) placeholders. Otherwise check out the list on http://regular-expressions.info/